# Add terminal-only option to Grub in Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, grub2

I have recently installed Debian Jessie, now I want the Grub menu to show two options: 1) normal GUI and 2) terminal/text only.

I've found many tutorials showing how to add a different Operating System to Grub, but this is not my case. I only need text mode to do some heavy processing in R, so I need to free as much memory as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Grub entry with the kernel parameter `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`. This is parsed by systemd, which boots to multi-user instead of graphical.target, which is the normal default.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to have both options in the Grub menu, not to switch configuration files every time I need the other boot.

Comment: That was my point exactly. Add a second boot entry that is identical to the one you have now, except that it has the extra kernel parameter (the labels should be different too, of course.) Then you choose between these entries at boot time.

Comment: Thanks again. Only that "identical" is kind of problematic. In /etc/grub.d/ I have 10_linux > 12 KB and 40_custom = 214 bytes. Not sure at all what to copy.

Comment: From [Grub2/CustomMenus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus): "The surest way to build a custom menu is to copy one or more working menuentries from the grub.cfg file".

Answer (score 0):

Then simply don't start your display manager, e.g. `gdm`.

```
systemctl disable gdm
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to have both options in the Grub menu, not to switch configuration files every time I need the other boot.

Comment: wtf? you can anytime start the graphic interface with `systemctl start gdm`. there is no need for reboot.

Comment: Good to know. But other people (not so tech-savvy) use my computer, so I want to make things easier to them. Also, I'm using the GUI most of the time, so it would ideally be the default menu option.

Comment: Then make gdm the default, and you can anytime stop it with `systemctl stop gdm`. You are smart, you can remember this easy command. (gdm eats about 10-20mb ram... i wonder how much memory is in that computer, when +20mb ram does matter)

Comment: gnome-shell: 215.0 MiB Memory + 1.8 GiB Virtual Memory. Evolution-calendar-factory: 36.5 MiB Memory + 1.1 GiB Virtual Memory (1 GB for calendars?). I have 4 GB of RAM and I'm almost sure that not starting a service is much better than starting it and then stopping it.

Comment: Argh#2... Why have you login at gdm? I spoke about gdm, not the whole desktop. When you are on the login screen, _dont login_, press **ctrl+alt+f1**, and use the terminal. (calendar and other resource wasting thing are started _after_ you logon in gdm, so _dont logon_ in gdm)

Comment: Thanks. This seems a good solution. But why can't I get an answer to my initial question? Is this so difficult?

Comment: It's not the boot manager's job. Bootmanager exists for loading the kernel only. Then the kernel booting and pass the control to init. Init reads config files from /etc and decide whether to start gdm or not. grub is far-far away from gdm default config file. An example: you also can't have 3 windows10 bootmenu: 1) boot with default browser edge, 2) boot with default browser firefox 3) boot with default browser chrome and start it with startpage http://why.cant.i.request/this/feature?

Comment: The solution for your original answer is: install two independent debianjessie onto 2 independent partition with a shared /home, and configure the 1st debian for console only, and configure 2nd debian to start gdm. Then you can choose from grub.

Comment: Interesting. So what do you think of the other answer?